# multiple replacing in resharper (Single, Count methods etc)

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-9.1

Resharper allows to replace only one issue. How to replace all same issues in entire proect?

For example, to replace

```
ctx.Shops.Where(t => t.ShopId == currentBase.ID).Single()
```

by

```
ctx.Shops.Single(t => t.ShopId == currentBase.ID)
```

you should push button as shown in the

[image]

How to replace all accurances of Sinle method in entire project?

Version of resharper 9.1 and 10

Comment: Bottom option doesn't have a options like `to this document`, `to this project`, `to this solution` or something with arrow sign (`>`) ?

Comment: Soner Gönül, nope. That item has some params with other purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, fixing this for entire file/project/solution (aka ["fix in scope"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/10.0/Code_Analysis__Fix_in_Scope.html)) does not seem to be supported.

The closest I could think of is selecting `Inspection "Replace with single call..."` > `Find similar issues...`, and then navigate between the results and fix manually.

Comment: yes, i tried that. But it takes too much time in big projects to apply this operation manually